# Write sets from python to a gdx

Tags: python, gams-math

I have a DataFrame with different columns in python that I have to use in GAMS as SETS and I do not know how to pass them to GDX from Python. What I want is that in the GDX I can specify the type of element that is like this example:

[image]

I'm trying this but I'm getting an error:

```
import gdxpds
Sets.to_gdx(os.path.join(sFile_path_output1 + 'tablaSETS' '.gdx'),index = False)
```

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: What version of GAMS are you using? If it's relatively recent (44+), you should use GAMS transfer

https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_OVERVIEW.html